# Finding a common derivative

Tags: calculus

Two small arches have parabola shapes. The first is described by $f(x)=1-x^{2}$ for $-1<x<1$ and the second is given by $g(x) = 4-(x-4)^{2}$ for $2<x<6$. A board is placed on the arches. Find the slope of the board, given that board does not rest on the tops of either arch.

Comment: How long is the board?

Comment: @Mathlovin  I believe the intention is that the board is more than long enough to rest across both arches.  It is certainly true that one could get different results for  shorter boards, but then one would not get a result by using a single derivative.  (I agree that the problem statement is a little sloppy...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the equality of  the expressions for the derivatives $ \ f'(x) \ $ and $ \ g'(x) \ $ to show that $ \ x_1 = x_2 - 4 \ , $ these being the unknown $ \ x-$ coordinates of the tangent points on the left and right parabolas.  Write, say, the equation of the tangent line to the left parabola, $ \ y - [1 - x_1^2] \ = \ [f'(x_1)] \ \cdot \ (x - x_1) \ $ ; the tangent point $ \ (x_2 \ , \ 4 - (x_2 - 4)^2 ) \ $ must also be on this line.  You should then have the information to find both tangent points; the slope of the board will follow from there.

Here's a picture of the arrangement:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful.

Comment: (+1) It's a pity such good and clean answers sometimes get so few upvotes. But at least you got mine!